# Rank, degree and slope of a general coherent sheaf

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be a ringed space and $\mathcal F$ be a coherent sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules on $(X,\mathcal O_X)$. Are there the definitions of rank, degree and slope of $\mathcal F$ in this general situation? I've seen only definitions for different particular cases. For example, if $X$ is a projective algebraic variety together with an embedding $X \to \mathbb P^N$ and with $\dim X = \dim \mathcal F = d$ then one defines first the Hilbert polynomial
$$
   P(\mathcal F,m) = \chi(\mathcal F \otimes \mathcal O(m)) \equiv \sum_{i=0}^{d} \alpha_i(\mathcal F) \frac{m^i}{i!},
$$
where $\mathcal O(m)$ is the bundle on $X$ induced by $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^N}(m)$,  and then puts $\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank} \rank \mathcal F = \frac{\alpha_d(\mathcal F)}{\alpha_d(\mathcal O_X)}$ and $\deg \mathcal F = \alpha_{d-1}(\mathcal F)- \rank(\mathcal F) \alpha_{d-1}(\mathcal O_X)$ and finally $\DeclareMathOperator{\slope}{slope} \slope \mathcal F = \frac{\deg \mathcal F}{\rank \mathcal F}$. Another special case is when $X$ is a compact Kahler manifold with the Kahler form $\omega$ and $\mathcal F$ is a torsion-free holomorphic vector bundle, when $\rank \mathcal F$ is the rank of the vector bundle and
$$
   \deg \mathcal F = \int\limits_X c_1(\mathcal F) \wedge \omega^{n-1}.
$$

But what are the definitions of these quantities for example in the case of a complex manifold $X$ (possibly, Kahler) but when $\mathcal F$ is a general coherent sheaf?

Comment: There is no reasonable definition for degree unless, maybe, with respect to a fixed, very ample invertible sheaf, i.e. you fix a projective embedding. My reason for saying this is simply the fact that you can *change* the degree of a projective variety by embedding it differently, for instance using Veronese embedding.

Comment: Thank you, @JeskoHüttenhain. I've just found this paper http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/40592/1/WRAP_THESIS_Green_1980.pdf where the author defines Chern classes for analytic coherent sheaves, so maybe the bundle-like definition of degree can be transported to the case of analytic coherent sheaves over compact Kähler manifolds?

Comment: Well, frankly I am unsure. But a compact Kähler manifold is a projective variety iff it is a Hodge variety, that much I happened to pick up. In this case, your definition of degree should coincide with "the degree" of this projective variety, but you cannot formulate the latter notion without a reference to the embedding, which as I said, is not unique. So maybe your notion of degree is not what I am used to.

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain very interesting situation. In S. Kobayashi's book "Differential geometry of complex vector bundles" (1987) the degree is defined for any analytic coherent sheaf $\mathcal S$ via its first Chern class which is by definition the first Chern class of the associated $\det \mathcal S$ line bundle.